# What to do with fields that can only be assigned non-null values after the object is created (Java)

Tags: java, null, variable-assignment, factory, builder

Suppose I'm making a game:

```
public class Game {

    Board board;
    public ArrayDeque<Player> players;

    //Players can have 'knights' and the one with the largest number
    //is referenced by the game.
    public Player playerWithLargestArmy;

    ...

}
```

At the beginning, when a game like this is initialised, no player can have the largest army (a player only has an 'army' once they have a certain number of knights). I want to assign the playerWithLargestArmy a value, but I'm not sure what. I also don't want to use `null` since I could just leave the implicit assignment to do that (and using null is bad practice anyway).

I am looking for someone to explain to me how I can resolve this issue. I looked up factories and builders but I'm not sure they handle this kind of delayed assignment. For context, each player has an int field specifying how many knights they have.

I could resolve this with a boolean for each player saying whether or not they have the largest army, but then you'd need to iterate through the players to find that player, which isn't ideal. Even if, in my case, that isn't a huge sacrifice, I'd still like to know for future reference.

Comment: And yes, I did look this question up on stack overflow. Couldn't find anything. Wouldn't ask if I had.

Comment: When did using `null` become "a bad practice anyway"?

Comment: You may want to look into Null Object patterns https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Robert C Martin made frequent mention of how one should avoid using null in code, but instead to use exceptions or special objects.

Comment: @DanielSoutar One should not take this philosophical suggestion literally, though. There are situations when `null` is the right option.

Comment: @Joe So essentially just create an empty class as a placeholder?

Comment: @DanielSoutar I have added an answer that includes an example. But Null Object patterns are meant for exactly your situation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is `java.util.Optional<T>` class for such case.

It have `isPresent()` and `get()` (and several other) methods which give you ability to check that object is present and get instance of underlying object.

**Examples**

Declaration

```
 Optional<Player> playerWithLargestArmy = Optional.empty();
```

Assignment of value

```
playerWithLargestArmy = Optional.of(newValue);
```

Usage of value

```
if(playerWithLargestArmy.isPresent()) {
    Player p = playerWithLargestArmy.get();
}
```

or even better

```
playerWithLargestArmy.map(p -> doSomethingWithIt(p));
```

which will invoke `doSomethingWithIt` only if value is present.

Comment: Are you going to explain how to use it in this case?

Comment: @takendarkk you read my mind. But talex, could you give some idea as to what that class does?

Comment: Added some explanation. You can find more in `JavaDoc`

Comment: Added usage examples.

Comment: @talex this is really handy! Thanks for this.

Answer (score 2):

Null Object Pattern
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern

```
public class Army {
    public static final Army NullArmy = new Army(0);
    private int size;

    public Army(int size) {
        this.size = size;
    }
}
```

Now when you create a new Army, just set the initial value to Army.NullArmy.